# How many parameters does the main function take?

Tags: iphone

I am a iPhone beginner and i want to know how many parameters the main function takes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main() function is a standard C main().  It takes two parameters:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {}
```

As Isaac notes, usually you will use the *main.m* provided for you by XCode:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you generally don't touch the main method.

typically you begin entering your code in your application delegate, specifically:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
```